# Dynamically adding textbox in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am working on an app and need to add a textbox to the View when a button is selected.  How can I do that or add any object dynamically.  What class do I use or what method do I need to call? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to call the `addView` method to the target view.  It's a method inherited from [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html), see [here][2].

[2]:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to define it in your layout XML, and set:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

Then in your code you can do:

```
TextView myTextBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextBoxId);
myTextBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and to hide it again:

```
myTextBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Here is the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29)